# " how to count the string in list as - lst=('abcdefgabc')". output should be a=2, b=2, c=2, d=1, e=1, f=1, g=1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to count the count of string where `lst=('abcdefgabc')`

```
lst=('abcdefgabc')
for i in lst:
    lst.count(i)
    print(i,(lst.count(i)))
```

output should be `a=2, b=2, c=2, d=1,e=1,f=1,g=1`

Comment: How is this different from the output you are getting?

Comment: if you need the `=`, just add it as one more arg in the `print` function

Comment: Related: [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2600191/4518341)

Comment: See answers referring to `Counter` in duplicate.

Comment: Try `collections.Counter("abcdefgabc")`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  We expect you to make a reasonable search for a solution before you post.

Comment: Side-note: Those parens around your string are pointless; `lst = 'abcdefgabc'` would mean the same thing, and not risk confusing people (e.g. with the name `lst`, I skimmed over it reading it as `list('abcdefgabc')` and thought you were pointlessly converting to `list`, rather than assigning a string to the name `lst`).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
lst=('abcdefgabc')
new_list = []
for i in lst:
    a = i+"="+str((lst.count(i)))
    new_list.append(a)
b = sorted(set(new_list))
print(b)
for x in b:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
['a=2', 'b=2', 'd=1', 'c=2', 'f=1', 'e=1', 'g=1']
a=2
b=2
d=1
c=2
f=1
e=1
g=1
```

Comment: There is no need for two `lst.count(i)`'s. Edit: There is no need for **three** `lst.count(i)`s. Count it once and store it as a local variable if you need it later in the loop. This is looping over `lst` `3*len(lst)` times. 3 times for each element.

Comment: Thank you so much, however we don't required the output double. eg. a=2 is showing twice. It should be displayed once.

Comment: Edited! I hope this works well for you now.

Comment: Great Thanks to you. Yes that was the same which I was looking for. :)

Comment: @PPSinha if this solves your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer!

Comment: Note that the OP seemed to want the output in order; changing `list(set(new_list))` to `sorted(set(new_list))` would accomplish that. Without sorting, the output order will actually vary from run to run (due to hash salting).

Comment: True, thanks for your suggestion, I edited my answer to contemplate it.